# Oracle group by ordered values

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
[Date] [hour] [valid] [value] [type]
```

And I need to do the averange for each hour of the 23 previous values and itself (24 values) and only if I have 18 or more valid values.

I do with one hour with this query:

```
select type, avg(value) 
from table 
where type = 10 
and valid = 1
and ((date = '11/10/2016' and hour <= 22) or
     (date = '11/09/2016' and hour > 22))
group by type
having count(*)>=18;
```

But I need to do it with a date interval for each hour in that interval.
It can be possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have `hour` value separated from `date` value? What is the data type of `Date` column?

Comment: why there is `hour >= 22 or hour < 22` what means just day is taken

Comment: I have Hour as a separated value, yes, I think the db designer has mental problems, so ... :) and Hour goes from 1 to 24, so ... I have nightmares with this ..., and yes, I have to make daily average for each hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but keeping date separately with hour is not good. So I'll merge it into date in `with` clause. If you don't want that you can use `to_date(date || ':' || hour, 'dd/mm/yyyy:hh24')` everywhere where I have `d` and ignore `with` clause

```
with dat as (select to_date(date || ':' || hour, 'dd/mm/yyyy:hh24') d, valid, value, type from table)
select d1.d, d1.type, avg(d2.value) 
  from dat d1 cross join dat d2 
  where d1.d < (d2.d + 1) and d1.d >= d2.d and d2.valid = 1
  group by d1.d, d1.type 
  having count(*) >= 18;
```

I hope it will work. If you provided any test data I would test it.

Comment: Yes, I works, I have to make one small change (hour-1) because my hour goes from 1 to 24 (and it makes me crazy) and one output from this hour again in a separated column, but, works great, Thank you very much.

Comment: @Darkerviti you can handle hour during conversion to date by `case when hour = 24 then to_date(date || ':' || '00', 'dd/mm/yyyy:hh24') + 1 else to_date(date || ':' || hour, 'dd/mm/yyyy:hh24') end d`

Answer (score 0):

you may write next, I assume column `valid` contains `Y` and `N` values.

```
select type
       ,max(avg1)
from (
select type
      ,avg(value) over (order by trunc(date,'HH') range between interval '24' hour preceding and interval '0' hour following ) as avg1
      ,count(decode(valid,'Y',1)) over (order by trunc(date,'HH') range between interval '24' hour preceding and interval '0' hour following ) as count1
from table
where type = 10 
and valid = 1)
where count1 >= 18
group by type;
```

Comment: No, valid is 1, 25 is not valid, 24 is maintenance and there are other error codes, but only 1 is valid.